# High power drain on idle, low power drain if cpu has load

Tags: power-management

I'm having a very strange issue for quite a long time and I just cannot find out what is causing it.

My idle load is around 220-240 Watts, which is way too much. I tried a lot of things to figure out what is draining these watts, but to no avail.

The graphic card is in idle mode, core and mem clock is low, it claims to drain around 10 watts (which I call shenanigans, given I have three monitors and 1 VR headset attached, but okay).

CPU is in lowest power state most of the time, it hardly has any work to do when the system is idle.

Here are some specs of my computer:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
KERNEL: 5.8.12
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core
GPU: AMD AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT (NAVI10, DRM 3.38.0, 5.8.12, LLVM 10.0.1)
GPU DRIVER: 4.6 Mesa 20.3.0-devel (git-62ba074 2020-09-29 focal-oibaf-ppa)
RAM: 32 GB
BOARD: Gigabyte X570 AORUS MASTER
CPU Governor: ondemand (2.20 to 3.8 GHz, boosts up to 4.45 GHz)
```

Now for the fun part:

If I artificially create *some* load (using `yes > /dev/null &`), say 3 threads at 100%, the power usage drops from 220-240 Watts to 130-140 Watts. With 3 threads its around 130 with spikes to 250W, with 4 threads its around 140 Watts stable. With 12 threads at 100% load, I'm still at 180 Watts only, which is way below the idle usage. If I remove the load, power usages goes back up to 220-240 Watts.

Can anybody please help me in fixing this? Why do I have such a high idle power usage and how do I get it down to sane levels?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What are you using to measure the power consumption?

Comment: Also, watch your CPU/GPU temperatures when the PC is idle. If they stay low, it is almost certainly not consuming 240W.

Comment: I have my pc plugged in a watt meter. It's not a super expensive one, but pretty reliable overall. Temperatures are 39 celsius for the GPU, 55 celsius for the CPU. The last one is actually a bit high for my taste (have a massive Noctua NH-D15 cooler and a good airflow overall), but might be normal. If my OS would still be windows, I'd tweak the voltages, but on linux I don't know how to do that unfortunately. Still, it's strange that the power consumption goes down when the load increases over a certain threshold (2 threads wont do it, it needs at least 3 threads, better 4).

Comment: I'm calling faulty/inaccurate watt meter. Again, watch your temperatures when changing between idle and loaded, if they behave as expected there is probably nothing wrong. Power consumption is practically equivalent to heat dissipation in a PC.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think you're right. It might have started to occur when I switched my power supply a year ago, not sure though. I've read a bit into the topic and it looks like the, sorry I don't know how to say it in English, curve of the power is more like a needle rather than a sinus curve, throwing the watt meter off. At higher loads the PFC kicks in and flattens the needles, bringing the curve closer to a sinus wave, so the watt meter is able to measure it again. That's the only way I can explain it. Guess I'll get a new watt meter and report back once I get one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue indeed was caused by the inability of my old watt meter to accurately measure the power drain of my new PSU at low loads. I got a new watt meter and it now reports 69W on the login screen and around 72-75W at an idle desktop. This finally makes sense.